# How to use some dynamic value in same query in mysql

Tags: mysql

How to use some dynamic value in same query in mysql, i.e. sum of three column will be used in select with some other field.

```
SELECT col1 + col2 + col3 AS cols, (clos + col4) * col5 FROM table
```

Answer (score 1):

In this kind of situation you must use variable to do this. 
Please try this ex. and it will works.

```
SELECT @result := col1 + col2 + col3 AS cols, (@result + col4) * col5 FROM table
```